# Excel Auto Numbering with Levels based on other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

tried google to no avail.  Can someone help with the Excel Formula so that I can achieve this number formatting?  Thanks in advance!

A. ColC = ColA + "." + auto number. Example, if ColA = 3, then ColC = 3.1, 3.2, etc.

B. ColE = ColC + "." + auto number. Example, if ColC = 3.2, then ColE = 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3

By auto number, I mean if I add a row, then the value is the next number value for that column (something similar to what Word does).

[image]

Comment: Why is E2:E3, the same while all the others adjust?

Comment: Scott.  Oh sorry. I was not able to edit it.  It is supposed to be 1.1.2 and 1.1.3. I've updated the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a count for that pourpose 
Assuming the column is b do

```
=b1&"."&countif($b$1:b1,b1)
```

Comment: Hi @user35183. I used your formula (ex. C2='A2&"."&COUNTIF($A$2,A2)', C3='A3&"."&COUNTIF($A$3,A3))', but that values are all 1.1 instead of 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc. when A2=1.  What am I missing?

Comment: @nikib sorry, i'm on móvil, planes try it now

Comment: Works on the ColC (2 levels) now.  I will implement something similar on the ColE (3 levels).  Thank you!

Comment: Another formula that might work (probably not the best way) to allow repeating numbers (ex. three 2.1's) is this '=IF(A1=A2,C1+0.1, A2+0.1)'